# I am having problems importing in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am coming up against an import error and i cannot see why if you could help me out pleasE.

my import statement is as below I use this method all the time without any problems, however its just not happening on this occasion any help would be appreciated

```
import * as agent from '../src/api/agent'

and I am exporting from the agent.js file the following 

import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000/api';

const responseBody = (response) => response.data;

const requests = {
    get: (url) => axios.get(url).then(responseBody),
    post: (url, body) => axios.post(url, body).then(responseBody),
    put: (url, body) => axios.put(url, body).then(responseBody),
    del: (url) => axios.delete(url).then(responseBody),
};

const MaskDetails = {
    list: () => requests.get('/maskdetails'),
    details: (id) => requests.get(`/maskdetails/${id}`),
    create: (maskDetail) => requests.post('/maskdetails', maskDetail),
    update: (maskDetail) => requests.put(`/maskdetails/${maskDetail.id}`, maskDetail),
    delete: (id) => requests.del(`/maskdetails/${id}`)

};



export default { MaskDetails }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure but try to export like this in agent.js

```
export default MaskDetails;
```

and also it seems like you are exporting just maskDetails so why

```
import * as agent from '../src/api/agent'
```

instead of

```
import agent from '../src/api/agent'
```

Comment: I have amended the import and exports to match your response Adir, however it looks like MaskDetails is undefined now ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'list' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you export like that

`export default { MaskDetails }` <<< export object with MaskDetails as key

and import

`import * as agent from '../src/api/agent'` <<< import all exported, so `export default` will on `agent.default`

access to `MaskDetails` will look like `agent.default.MaskDetails`